# Custom URL format for news in Expression Engine

Tags: url, expressionengine, disqus

Our site is migrating from MovableType to ExpressionEngine, and there is one small issue we are having. MT uses a date based URL structure, e.g. www.site.com/2012/03/post-title.html, while EE uses a category based structure, e.g. www.site.com/index.php/news/comments/post-title. The issue is that our MT page used Disqus for comments, and as such comments are tied to a specific URL, meaning that we'd lose all of our comments if we were to migrate. I am wondering if there's a way to change the URL structure in EE to match MT's, thus allowing us to keep the comments. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correction: EE uses a Template Group/Template based structure for URLs, not categories - just to clarify.

You've got a couple of options here.

One is to create an .htaccess rule which internally redirects all requests matching **YYYY/MM/** to your EE template which displays your posts (say, **/news/entry/**). I don't know exactly what those rewrite rules would look like off the top of my head, my mod_rewrite-fu is pretty shallow. But it could definitely work.

Another is to export all of your comments from Disqus via their XML export tool, then do a grep-based find and replace using something like BBEdit, replacing all **/YYYY/MM/** strings in that file with **/news/entry/**; delete all of your existing comments on Disqus; then import your newly-modifed XML file.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this should be enough to sort it out.

Comment: If search engine optimization means anything to you, you'll want to go with the .htaccess approach (with 301 status redirects) rather than allowing google to just treat all your old MT posts as 404s and the EE ones as new content.